# Steps to develop a website to upload files

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am planning to develop a webpage where anyone can upload a file. I want to do this because I want to make a webpage where my friends can upload a file, if they think that that file will help others (eg: a free tutorial pdf on Unix).

To develop and test this webpage what is needed ? As far as I think now:

1. Webserver ? I tried installing apache2 but had some issues
2. mysql-server ? I installed mysql-server ,but have issues with creating user for db
3. php

What else would I need ? (Assuming 'download' functionality will be added later, NOT NOW)

I am developing this in Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need MySQL for the problem as described. All that would be required is a web server with a working PHP install. You can see [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/features.file-upload) for how to handle the file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

once you have installed and configured wamp/lamp.
platform(window, linux) doesnt matter a web application is not platform dependent.  wamp/lamp will install mysql(database server), and apache(web server). thirdly determine you web scripting language(php, jsp, asp ect).if  php, your php scripts must be executed by the web server ie you have to place them under c:\wamp\www\sitefolder\

How to: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

you can test if on your local machine

then with Apache running, type in your browser www.localhost\sitefolder\yourscipt.php.

assuming you have an active domain and hosting account you may need to consider the 
::::
-determine the upload size limit, location, and file type on the php
-you may require/though not a must client side scriptiing jquery- ajax for asynchronous requests.
-security will be of concern, you dont want some harmful  data scripts on your site. 
verify upload limit with your hosing provider..